# Pass By Reference Multidimensional Array With Unknown Size

Tags: c++, c

How to pass by reference multidimensional array with unknown size in C or C++?

### EDIT:

For example, in main function I have:

```
int main(){
    int x, y;
    int arr[x][y];
    // pass_by_ref(/* passing just arr[][] by reference */);
}
```

and the function:

```
void pass_by_ref(/* proper parameter for arr[][] */){
    // int size_x_Arr = ???
    // int size_y_arr = ???
}
```

How to implement the commented line?

Comment: Make your choice - in C++ you can use `std::vector&` or other similar types, in C you need to specify the size as additional parameter or as first element (if you're using a integral type).

Comment: Actually, you can *only* pass an array by reference with unknown size!  (OK, there's a trick with a struct, but let's not go there).  What have you tried?

Comment: In C it's impossible because C has no references. In C++, it's impossible because it doesn't support variable length arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a multidimensional array to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155188/how-can-i-pass-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-function)

Comment: In C, in short, you don't. You must have a construct of *some* kind that dictates sizing at usage-time. How you gleen that size info is up to you.

Comment: How do you exactly define yours "multidimensional array with unknown size" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. In C, you can't pass by reference, since C has no references. In C++, you can't pass arrays with unknown size, since C++ doesn't support variable-lenght arrays.

Alternative solutions: in C99, pass a pointer to the variable-length array; in C++, pass a reference to `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`.

Demonstration for C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int n, int k, int (*arr)[n][k])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            printf("%3d ", (*arr)[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int b = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

    int arr[a][b];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }

    foo(a, b, &arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Demonstration for C++03:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void foo(std::vector < std::vector < int > > &vec)
{
    for (std::vector < std::vector < int > >::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++) {
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); j++) {
            std::cout << *j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int j = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);

    srand(time(NULL));

    std::vector < std::vector < int > > vec;
    vec.resize(i);
    for (std::vector < std::vector < int > >::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        it->resize(j);
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); jt++) {
            *jt = random() % 10;
        }
    }

    foo(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this line: `strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);`?

Comment: I would suggest to use `boost::array` in C++

Comment: I try to use this `void foo(int n, int k, int (*arr)[n][k])` and got `error: use of parameter 'n' outside function body`

Comment: @IfanIqbal I **compiled and run** this code. Are you compiling with `-std=c99`? (Also, spotting one error in the code should not make you unaccept my answer immediately.)

Answer (score 3):

H2CO3's solution will work for C99 or a C2011 compiler that supports VLAs.  For C89 or a C2011 compiler that *doesn't* support VLAs, or (God forbid) a K&R C compiler, you'd have to do something else.

Assuming you're passing a contiguously allocated array, you can pass a pointer to the *first element* (`&a[0][0]`) along with the dimension sizes, and then treat it as a 1-D array, mapping indices like so:

```
void foo( int *a, size_t rows, size_t cols )
{
  size_t i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
      a[i * rows + j] = some_value();
    }
  }
}

int main( void )
{
  int arr[10][20];

  foo( &arr[0][0], 10, 20 );
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

This will work for arrays allocated on the stack:

```
T a[M][N];
```

and for dynamically allocated arrays of the form:

```
T (*ap)[N] = malloc( M * sizeof *ap );
```

since both will have contiguously allocated rows.  This will *not* work (or at least, not be guaranteed to work) for dynamically allocated arrays of the form:

```
T **ap = malloc( M * sizeof *ap );
if (ap)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
  {
    ap[i] = malloc( N * sizeof *ap[i] );
  }
}
```

since it's not guaranteed that all the rows will be allocated contiguously to each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of comment to the good answer of @John Bode

> This will not work (or at least, not be guaranteed to work) for
>   dynamically allocated arrays of the form:

But this variant will:

```
T **ap = malloc( M * sizeof *ap );
if (ap) return NULL;     ---> some error atention
if (ap)
{
  ap[0] = malloc( M * N * sizeof *ap[i] );
  if (ap[0]) { free(ap); return NULL;}     ---> some error atention
  size_t i;
  for (i = 1; i < M; i++)
  {
    ap[i] = ap[0] + i * N;
  }
}
```

After use :

```
free(ap[0]);
free(ap);
```

for `T` being `int` you call `foo` exactly als for the array `int ap[M][N];`

```
  foo( &ap[0][0], M, N);
```

since you guaranteed that all the rows are allocated contiguously to each other. 
This allocation is a litter more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

John Bode's explanation is very good, but there is a little mistake:
it should be

```
i * cols + j
```

instead of

```
i * rows + j
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want references, then it's only in C++.

En example of a two-dimensional int array passed by reference

```
void function_taking_an_array(int**& multi_dim_array);
```

But the reference doesn't have any advantage, so simply use :

```
void function_taking_an_array(int** multi_dim_array);
```

I would advice you to use a container to hold your array.

Comment: Ehum, no. `int **` is a pointer to pointer to int, it's not a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: which could represent a bidimensional array. Using predefined array size or semaphor value (or specifying dimensions as additional parameters). The best example for that is the `main` function, with the `char** argv` function representing an array of char array.

Comment: It certainly can *emulate* them, if you use `malloc()` and pass in sizes, and whatever. But (double) pointers are still not (two-dimenisional) arrays.